# Python Tkinter - How to put widgets from one class onto a window in another class

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a window from the MainGUIApp class, and I have some widgets from another class that I want to place on this MainGUIApp class. How would this be done?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Tk, Menu, Label, StringVar, OptionMenu, Entry, Button, messagebox, Canvas, HORIZONTAL, Text, END

class MainGUIApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, window_title, window_width, window_length):

        # Window settings
        super(MainGUIApp, self).__init__()

        self.title(window_title)

        # get screen width and height
        ws = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = self.winfo_screenheight()

        # calculate position x, y
        x = (ws / 2) - (window_width / 2)
        y = (hs / 2) - (window_length / 2)
        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (window_width, window_length, x, y))

        self.current_directory = "C://Path"
        self.current_company = "Test_Company"

        self.top_panel = TopPanel.TopPanel(self, self.current_directory, self.current_company)
```

Where TopPanel class looks like this:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import ttk, Tk

class TopPanel(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent_frame, current_directory, current_company):
        super(parent_frame, self).__init__()
        self.current_directory = current_directory
        self.show_current_directory()

    def show_current_directory(self):

        # Have a text for current directory, pad y by 20, and set anchor to w (west)
        if self.current_directory is None:
            current_directory_text = Label(self,
                                           text="Current Directory:" + '                               '
                                                + "No directory assigned",
                                           font=("Helvetica", 12), anchor='w', pady=20)
        else:
            current_directory_text = Label(self,
                                           text="Current Directory:" + '                               '
                                                + self.current_directory,
                                           font=("Helvetica", 12), anchor='w', pady=20)

        current_directory_text.grid(row=0, sticky="w")
```

**But the problem is:** TopPanel opens up as a new window. I want TopPanel components to be a part of MainGuiApp.

Comment: What is the line you are using to import Tkinter? Not on windows, but `import Tkinter` and inheriting from `Tkinter.Tk` is what works on linux.

Comment: @jackw11111 I've added the import lines to my code. Also I am using windows.

Comment: When you use `import tkinter as tk` as the only import statement, see if inheriting from `tk.Tk` works.

Comment: So `class TopPanel(Tk.tk)` becomes `class TopPanel(tk.Tk)` and the same change for `MainGuiApp`.

Comment: @jackw11111 this works! but it creates a new window for TopPanel. How can I have the contents of TopPanel on MainGuiApp

Comment: You will need to consult the documentation for `tkinter`, but the basic idea is `TopPanel` will need to inherit from some type of container widget and to make it a child view to the main window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short your `TopPanel` needs to inherit from `tk.Frame`:

`class TopPanel(tk.Frame):`

Change the line so that you are initializing `tk.Frame`with:

`super(TopPanel, self).__init__()`

And when initializing the `TopPanel` instance, be sure to position it with:

`self.top_panel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Tk, Menu, Label, StringVar, OptionMenu, Entry, Button, messagebox, Canvas, HORIZONTAL, Text, END

class MainGUIApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, window_title, window_width, window_length):

        # Window settings
        super(MainGUIApp, self).__init__()

        self.title(window_title)

        # get screen width and height
        ws = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = self.winfo_screenheight()

        # calculate position x, y
        x = (ws / 2) - (window_width / 2)
        y = (hs / 2) - (window_length / 2)
        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (window_width, window_length, x, y))

        self.current_directory = "C://Path"
        self.current_company = "Test_Company"

        self.top_panel = TopPanel(self, self.current_directory, self.current_company)
        self.top_panel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import ttk, Tk

class TopPanel(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent_frame, current_directory, current_company):
        super(TopPanel, self).__init__()
        self.current_directory = current_directory
        self.show_current_directory()

    def show_current_directory(self):

        # Have a text for current directory, pad y by 20, and set anchor to w (west)
        if self.current_directory is None:
            current_directory_text = Label(self,
                                           text="Current Directory:" + '                               '
                                                + "No directory assigned",
                                           font=("Helvetica", 12), anchor='w', pady=20)
        else:
            current_directory_text = Label(self,
                                           text="Current Directory:" + '                               '
                                                + self.current_directory,
                                           font=("Helvetica", 12), anchor='w', pady=20)

        current_directory_text.grid(row=0, sticky="w")

main = MainGUIApp("test", 500, 500)
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you are going to use code based on another answer, it might be good to mention that.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!!